Ubuntu not letting me increase brightness
All of a sudden while working on my laptop running Ubuntu 24.04 the brightness toggle bar automatically going to zero and leaves the screen at lowest brightness level. When I try to increase brightness, it is not letting me to do so and again goes to zero by itself. All automatic brightness settings are disabled and screen sleep is set to never. How do I solve this? Please help. Thanks!
